# How to make a loop repeat forever?

Tags: c#, string

I am basically just wondering how can I make this while loop repeat continuously forever? I just can't figure out how to do it. once it reaches the end of the string it throws an exception. I have tried goto but it didn't work idk if i was just using it in the wrong play or what but i could get it work.

```
    private void checkBox2_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.checkBox2.Checked)
        {
            int startIndex = 0;
            string str = "hiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii";
            int length = str.Length;
            while (true)
            {
                Application.DoEvents();
                Thread.Sleep(200);
                startIndex++;
                string str2 = str.Substring(startIndex, 15);
                label2.Text = str2;
                if (startIndex == length)
                {
                    startIndex = 0;
                }
```

Comment: What kind of exception is your code throwing? That could be a clue as to the cause of the problem.

Comment: System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException
Index and length must refer to a location within the string.

Comment: Make sure you are able to exit the loop as well, you may run into problems later.

Comment: @ tcables i did i added an else with break; in it

Comment: Once you fix your index problem, you should seriously consider using a timer instead of this `while (true)` loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The last valid index in a string (or any array or list or collection) is always the length - 1, not length. Furthermore, since you are taking a substring of length 15, you actually want to stop 15 characters before the end. You'll want to change your if statement to be

```
if(startIndex == length - 16)
    startIndex = 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your while loop isn't the problem, it's your call to `Substring`.

Once `startIndex` becomes high enough, there aren't 15 more characters in the string...so `Substring` will thrown an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`.

To fix the problem, you need to change your if statement to something like:

```
if(startIndex == length - 16)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (startIndex + 15 == length)
{
    startIndex = 0;
}
```